# change underscores to hyphens in URLs with file names that begin with the word article

Tags: .htaccess

I tried using some code I found elsewhere on stackoverflow, but I want to modify it, and I don't know how.

```
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_+(.*)$ $1-$2 [E=underscores:Yes,N]
RewriteCond %{ENV:underscores} ^Yes$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

This changes all underscores to hyphens. However, I need to limit this set of statements to only URLs that begin:

http://www.mydomain.tld/article...

In other words, the rules should only apply when the file name begins with the word article.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

Try this and see if this and see if it works for you..

```
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_+(.*)$ $1-$2 [E=underscores:Yes,N]
RewriteCond %{ENV:underscores} ^Yes$
RewriteRule ^article(.+)$ /article$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Whups! I spoke too soon. This ended up crashing the server. Out of memory. <sigh>

Comment: That does what you asked. So as far as the question goes that answers your question. Plus I even tested it. If you are OOMing you need to find the root cause. Enable rewrite logging and also do other research via logs. Don't assume it's the rewrite. Something is going on with your server.