# htaccess convert underscores to hyphens for all files starting with the word "article"

Tags: .htaccess

I tried [another way to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22131228/change-underscores-to-hyphens-in-urls-with-file-names-that-begin-with-the-word-a), but it ended up crashing my server by using up all the memory.

My server admins came up with a second approach:

```
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_(.*)$ $1-$2-$3-$4-$5-$6-$7 [E=underscores:Yes]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_(.*)$ $1-$2-$3-$4-$5-$6 [E=underscores:Yes]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_(.*)$ $1-$2-$3-$4-$5 [E=underscores:Yes]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_(.*)$ $1-$2-$3-$4 [E=underscores:Yes]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)_(.*)$ $1-$2-$3 [E=underscores:Yes]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_(.*)$ $1-$2 [E=underscores:Yes]    
RewriteCond %{ENV:underscores} ^Yes$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mydomain.tld/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This approach seems more stable and doesn't use up memory.

The only problem is that this approach affects all files on the server, not just files that start with the word "article", such as http://www.mydomain.tld/article...

That doesn't work because this is a WordPress installation, and it tries to change all WordPress theme files that use underscores, rendering significant parts of the website unusable.

Can anyone suggest a way to modify this code to make it only apply when the word "article" is involved file name part of the URL?

Comment: You keep asking the same question and they are answered. I don't believe the rewrites are causing the memory issue. There is something else going on in connection with your wordpress site. There are plenty of servers that use such a rewrite and don't have that problem. The earlier answer was also fine. All your sys admin did was give you another code to try from here http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/rewrite-underscores-hyphens-seo-url.html. You need to have them find the `real` reason. There are at least 3 other SO questions with similar rewrites and no memory issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that there was, indeed, a solution to my inquiry. The following modification worked just fine:

```
RewriteRule ^article([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_(.*)$ $1-$2-$3-$4-$5-$6-$7 [E=underscores:Yes]
RewriteRule ^article([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_(.*)$ $1-$2-$3-$4-$5-$6 [E=underscores:Yes]
RewriteRule ^article([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_(.*)$ $1-$2-$3-$4-$5 [E=underscores:Yes]
RewriteRule ^article([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_(.*)$ $1-$2-$3-$4 [E=underscores:Yes]
RewriteRule ^article([^_]*)_([^_]*)_(.*)$ $1-$2-$3 [E=underscores:Yes]
RewriteRule ^article([^_]*)_(.*)$ $1-$2 [E=underscores:Yes]

RewriteCond %{ENV:underscores} ^Yes$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mydomain.tld/article$1 [R=301,L]
```

Panama Jack: if I were you, I wouldn't assume that the other solutions given weren't problematic, because as it turned out, they were. I can't say why, but I know that this solution stopped the memory drain and allowed the server to function normally. Are there other things that contribute to a memory drain? Of course! But that doesn't mean that the previous solutions I received couldn't also contribute to the memory issue.

Answer (score 0):

Replace all of your rules with these 2 rules:

```
RewriteRule "^(article)/([^_]*)_+([^_]+_.*)$" /$1/$2-$3 [N]
RewriteRule "^(article)/([^_]*)_([^_]*)$" /$1/$2-$3 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: He's probably still going to have issues with OOMing because the answer he asked before worked just fine as well. I suspect other problems.